# Can I install a dualboot and start the windows boot from linux terminal?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows

So I've been having fun so far with my new linux installation.

For some programs I need to run for school I need to install a dualboot for windows, but I don't like the grub loader where you need to choose which installation to run.

I just want it to start my linux installation and if I want to go to windows I want to use a terminal command or something from within the linux installation to go to the windows installation.

so is this possible? and if so how?

--------------SOLUTION----------

[How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

You cannot generally switch from one running operating system to another. You would always need to reboot to do that.

Alternatively you can install a *new* instance of Windows inside a virtual machine that runs from inside of Linux. You would then be able to resume and suspend that virtual machine without rebooting to use alongside Linux.

Comment: so then there isn't a command to tell the grub to start windows on next boot, instead of the default linux (in this case)

Comment: Yes, it's possible to tell grub to have another default setting during the next boot. Please open a new question, if you want to pursue that path (after doing your own research).

Comment: Okay, with that my question is answered, I'd been looking for it some time now but could not find the command, but now I think I know where I should look. Thank you very much!