# Boot another OS from terminal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 13.10.I had another two Os's installed on my HDD.

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda8:Ubuntu 13.04 (13.04):Ubuntu:linux
```

My grub menu shows all the three Os's on startup.I don't had any problem with booting.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to **directly** boot into `/dev/sda8:Ubuntu(13.04)` OS, by applying some commands on `Ubuntu 13.10 terminal` OR using any other `softwares`.(**Without showing grub menu on startup**)

Comment: This method lets you boot into another OS from a launcher or command line: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu It will not show grub (but the reboot will run past it ;) ) Any reason for the "without showing grub"? (besides aesthetics?)

Comment: it shows reboot into windows from ubuntu,i am asking for reboot into another version of ubuntu.I think some modifications we need to done on that answer to boot ubuntu 13.04 directly.

Comment: You do know the choice of the OS is optional? All you need to do is change the option you need. So the example stands as is, you need to configure it to your needs.