# How can I get grub2 to boot a different option only on the next boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-7

I am setting up a dual booting headless Linux / Windows machine. I mostly want the machine to always boot up to Ubuntu, except for occasionally when I need to test something in windows.

I've installed Windows and Ubuntu, and currently it boots up to Ubuntu every time. I would like to be able to tell it to boot to Windows *on the next boot only* and then when I restart from Windows have the system return to booting Ubuntu.

I found [Grub Legacy - section 4.3.1 - Booting once-only](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html) but I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server which has the newer version of grub. From what I've read, I need to make some changes to `/etc/default/grub` and use `sudo grub-set-default` when I want to boot to Windows.

I think those changes start with adding this to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=false
```

Anytime changes are made to `/etc/default/grub` I know that I need to then run
`sudo update-grub` and which results in:

```bash
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

Since Windows is the 7th option in that list I believe I would run `sudo grub-set-default 6` (0 based counting) - is this correct and is there a different method to get a numbered list of boot choices after the system is already booted?

Also, are the lines in `/etc/default/grub` sufficient to achieve this behavior or do I need to add additional configuration?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to make sure you have `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` in your grub config (which is autogenerated, you change this part of it by editing /etc/default/grub). `sudo update-grub` to make the changes active and then use `sudo grub-reboot $1`.

```
grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Will give you the menuentries that you can cut-paste in for $1. Or, as you note the options are zero-indexed, so the n-th menuentry can be had by passing (n-1) to grub-reboot.

See eg

- [How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot
- https://superuser.com/questions/285755/boot-to-windows-once-from-grub-then-back-to-ubuntu-on-next-boot.

Not tested by me as I don't have a 'Windows 7' install.

Comment: thanks i think this is what i need ( with additional details that I found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 )

Comment: If you happened to try this without changing the line to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`, you have to do this manually later like explained [here in the second paragraph for Grub2](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot) and then `grub-set-default 0; grub-reboot 0`

Comment: a command to show the numbers of the entry: `grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g"|nl -v 0`

Comment: As per https://askubuntu.com/questions/838704/grub-reboot-to-specific-kernel, `menuentry`s under a `submenu` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` must be passed to `grub-reboot` as `SUBMENU>MENUENTRY`.  So, for instance, using some bash-fu similar to @rubo77's, I wanted to boot `menuentry` 7, however this entry was under a `submenu` which was the second entry in the top-level menu, so I needed to pass `'1>6'` instead (single quotes to avoid the shell interpreting >).

Comment: WARNING: This doesn't work if you boot off a BTRFS partition.  Grub needs to be able to write to grubenv as it boots windows, it can't write to BTRFS.  The file is typically stored in /boot/grub and can be viewed with grub-editenv.  I fixed my system by mounting BTRFS in /, an EXT4 partition in /boot, and then the EFI partition in /boot/efi.

Comment: NOTE: it is not clear, that you only need the **line-number** minus 1 of the visible grub options during start, so if Windows is the 3rd line, just use `sudo grub-reboot 2; reboot`

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what grub2-once does. Please try it. Seems grub2-once is only available for linux distros from SUSE.

```
shiraz-1:~/:[0]# grub2-once --list
     0 SLES 15-SP1
     1 Advanced options for SLES 15-SP1>SLES 15-SP1, with Linux 4.12.14-195-default
     2 Advanced options for SLES 15-SP1>SLES 15-SP1, with Linux 4.12.14-195-default (recovery mode)
     3 Advanced options for SLES 15-SP1>SLES 15-SP1, with Linux 4.12.14-95.54.1.19924.5.TEST.1167133-default
     4 Advanced options for SLES 15-SP1>SLES 15-SP1, with Linux 4.12.14-95.54.1.19924.5.TEST.1167133-default (recovery mode)

shiraz-1:~/:[0]# grub2-once 3
shiraz-1:~/:[0]# reboot
```

Comment: How do I get `grub2-once` installed? I cannot find it in Ubuntu 20.04. maybe only OpenSuSE?

Comment: Unfortunately, seems yes. It's a Perl script written by employees from suse.com . You could find it by searching for latest grub2 package from opnesuse distro on http://www.rpmfind.info/

Comment: So better just use `sudo grub-reboot 3; reboot`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\' '/^menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg|cat -n|awk '{print $1-1,$1="",$0}'
```

That'll give you the numbers and names of the available grub boot menu options.

Answer (score -4):

Try installing **grub-customizer** (installation guide below) to your Ubuntu system. This GUI tool will provide you a nice set of options with that you can configure your GRUB settings, including names and order of the boot options, default system, screen resolution, fonts, background etc...
I am not sure if it has the ability to directy set what you want, but at least it can show you the os numbers. They can be referenced by their name too, I think.

How to install grub-customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

(source: [launchpad - daniel richter](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer))

Comment: I saw that tool, but I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server ( no GUI ) so I'd love to have a command line solution.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this. I use 14.10 standard (Unity) and I personally prefer GUIs for jobs like these.  
Do you know [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html) site? It describes about what you wrote in your question, but if it differs from your first source, maybe there you find what exactly you need.

Comment: -1 - I'm downvoting your answer because I wonder if you read the question at all. I can understand that you may have missed 'ubuntu server' in there but you just posted the same link that I included in my question in your last comment...

Comment: Oops. But do you think every time I write a new comment or answer I re-read the whole question and former postings, checking every link!? Besides, you can also install DEs on server distros! I admit that I am no expert (yet), but at least I try helping others where I can, even if the answers are not always 100% correct or useful. You should be glad that there is anybody trying to help you solving this problem, but if you want to piss me off, you succeeded. One last thing: you talked about `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=false`, but I can't find this on our link. And you forgot other lines mentioned there!