# Grub: reboot to specific kernel

Tags: grub2

I'd like to ask for help getting `grub-reboot` to work.

The theory: According to [this blog post](https://statusq.org/archives/2012/10/24/4584/) (and other sources) I should be able to choose the kernel for the next reboot, using `grub-reboot`. However, this does not work for me; grub always boots to the default kernel.

Here's what I tried:

```
$ grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
$ grep "menuentry " /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-43-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-43-generic-advanced-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-43-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-43-generic-recovery-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-advanced-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-recovery-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060' {

# Version 1, using the name
$ sudo grub-reboot "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic"

# Version 2, using the id
$ sudo grub-reboot gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-advanced-f3a807d1-3fd6-4970-b741-5382e9801060

# Version 3, counting
$ sudo grub-reboot 3
```

Neither of these commands seem to have an effect; after reboot, I always end up with the 4.4.0-43 kernel.

Note: This is on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. It is a server machine and I don't have access to the console during boot, so I can't look at the grub menu :(

Comment: "I don't have access to the server." How do you expect `grub-reboot` to work then?

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade your kernel? Also, you can delete newer kernels with apt-get purge.

Comment: Mark: Sorry, I have SSH access but no physical access. Trying to get an IPMI console to work now... that might help.

Comment: Patrick: I'm running into a bug with a newer version of the Kernel. The previous one worked. Also, AFAIK I can't `apt-get purge` the one kernel that's currently running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the kernel you want to boot is in a submenu of grub (just look at the complete `grub.cfg`). [`man grub-reboot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/grub-reboot.8.html) says:

> Please note that menu items in submenus or sub-submenus require  specifying  the  submenu  components  and  then the menu item component. The
>   titles should be separated using the greater-than character (`>`) with no
>   extra  spaces.  Depending on your shell some characters including `>` may
>   need escaping. More information about this is  available  in  the  GRUB
>   Manual in the section about the 'default' command.

Maybe something like `grub-reboot '2>2'` will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

### Display Grub Menu Entries from Command Line

I created a script `grub-menu.sh` to make it easy to find the menu entry number:

[image: grub menu.png]

---

### Booting with Grub Menu Entry Number

If you wanted to reboot into Kernel `4.4.0-131` you would use:

```
sudo grub-reboot "1>6"
```

---

### Getting the bash script `grub-menu.sh`

You can find the bash script in this Q&A: [Display grub menu and options without rebooting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019213/display-grub-menu-and-options-without-rebooting)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the script, that's handy.

Answer (score 3):

I've been in a similar situation, and wanted a simple way to reboot into a different kernel or set the default.  The menus that are generated in Ubuntu do make this less than trivial.

I've put together a script called [boot-kernel](https://gist.github.com/smoser/4d6371b9e3823b88a65c84ff40d1fd88) that makes this easier.  Its not perfect, but works well for at least official ubuntu kernels.

```
$ sudo ./boot-kernel --setup-only
changing GRUB_DEFAULT from 0 to "saved" in /etc/default/grub
apply change to /etc/default/grub
   --- /etc/default/grub    2018-01-12 19:40:38.681080878 +0000
   +++ /tmp/boot-kernel.GXbsRC  2018-01-12 19:40:50.525044373 +0000
   @@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
    # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
    #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

   -GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   +GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
execute: update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic
done

$ sudo ./boot-kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic
GRUB_DEFAULT already set to 'saved'. no change necessary.
selected /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic. entry: Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-108-generic
execute: grub-reboot "Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-108-generic"
```

Answer (score 1):

The next tips will be usable in case if you have a standard grub menu. If you have two sub-menus you need to change your sub-menu number from `1` to the other number your sub-menu has and change `-2` to the other value. For example, if you has `Submenu 2` on the 3rd position, you need to change that numbers to `2` and maybe `-3` in `menunum` variable setting.

Get list of kernels and output it:

```
    kernlist=$(grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g")
    printf "%s$kernlist\n"
```

Specifying kernel version we want to boot from:

```
    kernel=5.3.0-40-generic
```

Getting MENU_ENTRY number for our kernel if it is behind `Advanced options for Ubuntu` menu which has `1` MENU_ENTRY number:

```
    menuline=$($kernlist | grep -ne $kernel | grep -v recovery | cut -f1 -d":")
    menunum=$(($menuline-2))
```

Rebooting into desired kernel:

```
    sudo grub-reboot "1>$menunum" && reboot
```

**One-line solution that requires kernel version correction but without `reboot` command:**

`kernel=5.3.0-40-generic; menuline=$(grep -i "menuentry '" /boot/grub/grub.cfg|sed -r "s|--class .*$||g" | grep -ne $kernel | grep -v recovery | cut -f1 -d":") && menunum=$(($menuline-2)) && sudo grub-reboot "1>$menunum"`