# Ubuntu 18.04 only boots in Recovery mode

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, amd-graphics, nomodeset

It's an iMac, but it's been running ubuntu for maybe 5 years without serious issue.  Not my computer, so I don't know how this problem started.  With some web searching and guesses at where I should look, I found this info:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-54-generic

$ lspci |grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV610/M74 [Mobility Radeon HD 2400 XT]

$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    4.932133] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    4.932180] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

So I looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Do I need to enable kernel modesetting?  How do I do that?

I looked at https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting but I don't have an `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf` file.

I'm looking at combining https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273471/how-to-solve-drmradeon-init-radeon-error-no-ums-support-in-radeon-module and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1631395

No, I'm going to try this:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/660199

Currently editing `/etc/default/grub` to set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=1"`

Answer (score 0):

The `4.15.0-54` kernel came out late last month:

```
$ ll /boot/*4.15.0-54*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217286 Jun 24 08:45 /boot/config-4.15.0-54-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62979768 Jun 29 09:19 /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4050903 Jun 24 08:45 /boot/System.map-4.15.0-54-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8140856 Jun 25 06:23 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic
```

The easiest first step to try is rebooting and selecting the previous kernel version which hopefully still works:

[image: grub-menu.sh]

In this [facsimile of the grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019213/display-grub-menu-and-options-without-rebooting/1019214#1019214) on my system I would:

- first go into **Advanced options for Ubuntu**
- and then select `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-52-generic`

Comment: Thank you, but I've discovered with rebooting that I have to unplug and plug back in the power cord or it won't even make it to the Grub menu.  I think the hardware is toast, or at least unreliable and am going to buy a new one.