# How to enable HWE on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04, lts

I have an installation of Ubuntu 22.04 (desktop) that I did as soon as 22.04 was available, so it was 22.04.0 at the time. It's fully up to date and currently on 22.04.1 according to "lsb_release -a".

It doesn't seem like I have any of the "hwe" packages installed that I see some other people referencing online, like "linux-generic-hwe-22.04".

I guess installations of 22.04.1 come with HWE by default?

What is the proper way to switch to HWE officially for older installations of 22.04?

I know I can just install that kernel package, but what about mesa and anything else covered by HWE?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched your package manager for HWE?

Comment: AskUbuntu works best if you ask a single, clear, concise, answerable question. It's unclear which of those many questions should be the main axis of an answer.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack shows how it was done for prior releases.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I see some packages with “hwe” in the name, but I am not sure which, if any, should be installed. Documentation on Ubuntu’s website is conflicting since it says that hwe is enabled for desktop by default, but those hwe packages are definitely not installed on my system.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks. I did stumble across that page, but that’s what prompted this question. They list different procedures for the different Ubuntu LTS versions, so I didn’t want to assume that the procedure for 20.04 is the same as 22.04 (which isn’t listed there yet).

Comment: @Corvette1250 If they don't list an HWE procedure for 22.04, it's probably because it hasn't been offered as a package yet.  Normally it's only needed after a version has been out a while, in order to catch up with new hardware.  The HWE for 22.04, for instance, might not be offered until sometime in 2023; surely wouldn't have been before 22.10 dropped.

Answer (score 9):

To install HWE kernels run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

There is nothing else to be done.

Comment: Actually after rebooting and everything checking out you probably also want to run `sudo apt remove linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic` since you no longer need those kernel updates

Comment: For me that does install the hwe kernel, but grub doesnt seem to offer the hwe kernel as a boot option.

Comment: @jeremy_rutman - best to ask a new question for visibility.  Having said that, have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1019214/135930