# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS freezes few times per hour and very unstable

Tags: 22.04, freeze, ram, crash

Title shows the problem.Brand-new install. I selected minimal install because I don't need libre office. I only installed gpart, testdisk, edge beta, htop and discord.
Fresh install nothing installed and even on install disc it still crashes or freezes. Anything that requires a login makes the session crash like discord and the online accounts in settings.
The OS also has some weird render issues. Sometimes when watching YouTube it renders some weird block and snow thing on screen.
Also I saw in htop(resource monitor) showing memory spikes using up all memory.
I can not terminate the session using ctrl alt backspace when it freezes. The only thing that works is alt sysrq b.
I've used Ubuntu many times before, it wasn't unstable like this.
**note 'freeze' means mouse not working, keyboard works, speaker sometimes works, screen freezes.*

```
System info:
Hardware Model: ASUSTeK Computer INC. BM6835_BM6635_BP6335
Ram: dual 8GiB ddr3
GPU: GTX650ti boost
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
Drive: 1t total | 255MiB efi | 128GiBext4 ubuntu | 803GiB ntfs storage |
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64bit, GNOME V42.2, Windowing System: Wayland
```

BTW, I saw the graphics in about/settings, it shows NVE6?

Comment: It maybe because of the kernel. Have you installed kernel 5.15? Have you looked the logfile?

Comment: @Mahler Yes, I have 5.15.0-53-generic kernel, I'm checking the log, nouveau seems spaming the log with some weird memory ardess or things like "gr: GPC2/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 10000e [OOR_ADDR]" or "TRAP ch 4 [023fa01000 systemd-logind[1105]]"?

Comment: Also @Mahler I think i found the issue... "NO-APPLE-AREA kernel: [22990.850762] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 08 []
" message was spamming for three hours while the freeze

Comment: "minimal install" comes from an outdated Windows mentality. Here is NOT what you think it is. It should only be used by users who know what they're doing and WHY they're doing it, no exceptions. In your case you really need the full set AND Nvidia drivers as mentioned in the answer, but you may get away now by only installing the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I’m having the same issues, it is very frustrating, now finding out how to remove this Wayland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be your Nvidia drivers. Try `nvidia-smi` in terminal.

If it says something like "nvidia-smi not installed" or "can't communicate with drivers", that means your Nvidia driver is either not installed or disabled.

To install them run `apt search nvidia-driver`. A list should come up, and usually it's the best idea to install the latest driver unless your hardware is very old. The name of the driver will be something like `nvidia-driver-520`. Just type `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520` to install the drivers.

Then make sure to reboot.

Since you have a GTX 650Ti though, probably older drivers like `nvidia-driver-470`should also work well, maybe even better for your hardware.

EDIT: I just saw you were also using Wayland? Probably not a good idea considering you have an Nvidia GPU. Wayland support is horrible for Nvidia and whenever I tried using it I experienced really bad instability. To switch to XOrg, at the login screen choose your user, and in the bottom right, click the gear icon. Choose `XOrg` and log in.

Comment: I will try it after school, thank you.

Comment: What is this Wayland? Why does it get installed by default? And if it causes so many gpu driver issues how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the graphics driver or BIOS did not help. What worked was [enabling the HWE kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443187/1004020) to upgrade to 6.2.0-26-generic. There have been no freezes since, so it must have been a kernel bug fixed sometime in between.