# Ubuntu 20.04 screen artifacts during login

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

My Ubuntu 20.0 uses kernel 5.15.0-86-generic x86_64. When I put `nomodeset` in the grub boot menu this does not happen.

My PC uses AMD Radeon video drivers.

Ubuntu 20.04 screen artifacts during login:

[image: The screen has this glitch]

Comment: I have the same problem, I have a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 with (I think) AMD graphics which works fine when booting 5.15.0-84-generic kernel but screen goes blank/flickery just before/after logging in on 5.15.0-86-generic kernel.

FWIW I found some bug reports of others who also have the same problem here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2039378
and here:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=405762

But I haven't found any analysis/fix of what causes the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this happens only when my Ubuntu uses the kernel 5.15.0-86-generic x86_64. I changed it to kernel 5.15.0-84-generic x86_64 and the issue was gone.

Comment: This is a useful workaround but not a longterm fix, since I don't want to be stuck on an old kernel version forever.

Comment: People on this thread: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=405762 have reported that kernel 6.2 solves this issue for them, though I'm not sure how to get kernel 6.2 on ubuntu 20.04 - will look into that.

Comment: For anyone else in same situation: I upgraded to ubuntu 22.04, then switched to HWE kernel upgrades using [the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443187/537703), including the cleanup instructions in the comment. Worked for me.