How do I find and get the latest official Ubuntu Kernel that is not mainline kernel
If I understand this correctly on mainline I am currently running ubuntu kernel 6.11.
I'd like to install the latest official ubuntu kernel available that is not mainline I guess since mainline is just kernel.org?  How do I find this, and what would be the best way to install it.
I already have grub menu on boot to choose the version of kernel.

How did you originally manage to uninstall your Ubuntu kernel packages and metapackages and install mainline? You basically must follow a similar process in reverse. Without knowing what you did, any instructions we provide may be risky. We may use invalid assumptions.

You can have the latest official Ubuntu kernel for 22.04 by installing the Hardware Enablement packages. This answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442208/how-to-enable-hwe-on-ubuntu-22-04 explains how to do this.

The latest HWE kernel for 22.04 is 6.8; which is the latest that has guaranteed support in regards security patches & fixes; if you install newer kernels they may not get security patches (such as Ubuntu's testing kernels; they are created & provided 'as is' being intended for testing purposes).  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details on supported kernel stack options (GA, HWE & OEM)

@guiverc Thank you it answers my question

Ubuntu supplies security patches & updates only for supported kernels for a release.
An LTS release has kernel stack options, these are

GA or the initial kernel the release comes with; supported for the life of the product with security fixes applied when you perform updates

HWE or the hardware enablement kernel which comes from later releases; each kernel (from a non-LTS) is supported for six months before moving to the next, before the release settles on the GA kernel from the next-LTS release

OEM for specific hardware; Ubuntu Desktop and some ISOs will recognize certain hardware and install/use this if beneficial for the hardware detected during install.


You can of course change kernel stacks post-install, and multiple kernel stacks can co-exist on the install too (you select at grub which you'll boot with), however some closed-source kernel modules (eg. some NVIDIA drivers) can prevent multiple stacks from co-existing.
For details see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
The newest/latest support HWE kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is 6.8; which was the GA kernel stack from Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
If you install kernels from the Ubuntu Kernel team, ensure you read the support period as for security patching, as you'll discover rather quickly most are provided 'as is' with no security patches at all; ie. its safe to assume if you installed the kernel yourself (not from Ubuntu repository package) you took on the responsibility for applying security fixes too. The Ubuntu Kernel team provide their fixes via Ubuntu repository packages.
