# X1 updating kernel from 5.14.0-1034-oem on Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: apt, kernel, oem

I have an X1, seems my kernel is 5.14.0-1034-oem.
This is a 2004 kernel, but my system is 22.04.4.
The kernel has not been updated in a long time. I suppose I need to somehow remove the OEM kernel. I'm not sure how I got this OEM kernel to start with.

when I try `sudo apt remove linux-image-5.14.0-1034-oem` it says you're trying to remove the kernel that you are running.

I have all these kernels:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii.*linux-image"
ii  linux-image-5.14.0-1034-oem                5.14.0-1034.37                               amd64        Signed kernel image oem
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-101-generic             5.15.0-101.111                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic               6.5.0-26.26~22.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.15.0.101.98                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              6.5.0.26.26~22.04.13                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: Which kernel are you currently running? Please include output of `uname -a` in your question.

Comment: Also, it seems you should try and change the GRUB config to load a newer kernel by default. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838704/grub-reboot-to-specific-kernel).