# How to select the Kernel version on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, grub2, kernel, ssh, webserver

I installed a different kernel on my VPS, but it's not being used automatically and I can't select it in grub because I don't have access to the server during boot. How do I configure which kernel to use via ssh while it's booted up?

The kernel in use now came with the server image. The one I want to use now is the current generic kernel from the repositories.

Comment: Depending on the virtualization technology used by the host, it could also be that you must use the host kernel version and can not have your own... Not sure whether that is the case for you. However, normally when you install a kernel package with `apt`, it should automatically update the GRUB configuration to use the new kernel as default on the next reboot.

Comment: Unless you do something to configure ubuntu otherwise, it will always boot the most current. VPS, however, may or may not depending on VPS technology, LXC and Openvz, for example, will use host kernel and you have no control from the guest. Otherwise see https://askubuntu.com/questions/574295/how-can-i-get-grub2-to-boot-a-different-option-only-on-the-next-boot.

Comment: Thanks. My VPS uses OpenVZ and that mean I have to stick with that old kernel version.