# One power-button to boot windows 10 and the other with ubuntu?

Tags: windows, power-management, reboot

I am trying to find a way that if power button boots ubuntu and another button or pressed in conjunction with the power key can boot me to windows 10 instead. Is there any way that this is possible? Need help.

Comment: You can use [grub-reboot](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/grub-reboot/) command to boot to a specified OS only in the next boot. Take a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/575546/1001338) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have to find the grub entries present in your system via

```
grep -i "menuentry '" /etc/grub/grub.cfg
```

For ubuntu linux , the `menuentry` should look like this

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-18-generic (on /dev/sdaX)
```

and for Windows 10

```
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdaX)
```

so in order to boot to the windows next time you reboot , you have to make a shell script like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
grub-reboot "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdaX)"
reboot
```

You can save it as for example `boot_win.sh` and you have to make it executable(by default new shell scripts haven't the `exec` permission) via :

```
chmod +x /whatever/directory/it's/in/boot_win.sh
```

and
 [assign a custom shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) for it.