# How do I boot back to Ubuntu? (Booting from Windows to Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu some days ago, running alongside with Windows 10 (dual booting, I guess it's called). I booted Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, and after pressing F12 at PC startup (Windows Booting Menu?) and choosing to boot from USB, I was then sent to something called "GNU GRUB". It left me four options, *"Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", "OEM install" and "Check for disc defects".* I chose *"Install Ubuntu"*, and the whole installing process went fine after that. I used Ubuntu many times, shut down and turned my PC back on several times (my PC automatically booted back to Ubuntu without me having to do anything). Today I had to do some work in Windows, so I booted into Windows 10 today. Now, I don't know how to get back to Ubuntu. At PC startup, I press F12 and try to find a way to boot back to Ubuntu, but I can't find it! I then inserted my USB flash drive (with Ubuntu installed on it), and then after pressing F12 and choosing to boot from USB and not Windows (going into Windows Booting Menu), I'm led back to GNU GRUB. It let's me choose the same four options as before, but I don't want to install Ubuntu anew.

I want to be able to go back to my "old" Ubuntu, but I just don't know how. I know that if I choose "Install Ubuntu", all my old files and programs will dissapear, because Ubuntu will start totally fresh.
All my programming homework that I need to send in on Tuesday is on my "old" Ubuntu, so it's so important that I can access my old Ubuntu again. I've been trying to boot back to Ubuntu the entire day, but nothing I do seems to work, and my PC is very slow, so it's such a bummer to restart my PC all the time to get back to the Booting Menu.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

Comment: You have UEFI or legacy BIOS boot manager?

Comment: BIOS, I'm quite sure. (Sorry, I don't know much about this, I've never dealt with this before.)

Comment: If your computer came preinstalled with Windows 8/8.1, you have UEFI. In that case try this: http://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/

Comment: Thank you, but I just tried, and cmd tells me "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. Access denied." I don't get why, I'm pretty sure I'm the admin of my computer (I'm the only one that has ever used it, and I can run software and applications as administrator)

Comment: Not sure but often boot repair helps. Since you already have live USB, try to install boot repair. It automatically detects and fixes boot issues: http://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

Comment: I think it worked! I'm able to login back to my regular Ubuntu user! Problem now is that I'm stuck in a login loop. Anyway, thank you so much, you've been a great help! Thank you for solving my (first) problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu

Comment: Search for the login loop instead of making a new question (not accusing, just suggesting). Many people have had it.

Comment: Also suggestion:disable fast boot in Windows.

Comment: Thank you, but I already searched the forums right after the login loop occured, but nothing I tried worked, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu. All my files are gone, but Ubuntu seems to be running smoothly now, so I'll just make backups of all my programming homework from now on onto a USB flash drive, in case that happens again. :)
Thank you for all your help.