# Hibernate and restart immediately instead of powering off

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hibernate, restart

After figuring out how to reboot to Windows with `grub-reboot` thanks to this question:  [How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu), I would like to have Ubuntu hibernate and restart into Windows instead of rebooting.

Replacing `sudo reboot` with `sudo pm-hibernate` does work, by saving hibernation data and powering off the system. When I press the power button, It works as expected by booting to Windows.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can make the pc restart immediately after hibernation instead of having to press the power button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this using `s2disk` instead of `pm-hibernate` here: [Hibernate with reboot on Linux](http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2011/03/hibernate-with-reboot/)

I replace the command

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

with

```
sudo s2disk -P 'shutdown method = reboot'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same task from the Windows direction?

Comment: Not that I have found.