# Reboot into Windows from Ubuntu - reliably

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have dual boot, and used the most popular answer in this thread to create a script and desktop icon to reboot into Windows:
[How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu)

And, it works - UNTIL and only until there's a security update for Ubuntu.
The process of making the grub's default boot option 'SAVED' seems to get reset very frequently (weekly or more often than that) by security updates.
The steps that work -
edit the file `/etc/default/grub` so that

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

persists, but I guess the step

```
sudo update-grub
```

updates the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
which is replaced by security updates, so then the sudo update-grub required again.

Is there no way to have this persist through security updates?

Actually, just running `sudo update-grub` is not enough - I must make a change to the `/etc/default/grub` file for the `update-grub` to work. So, for example, `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, and just add a space, so the file changes and can be re-saved. then `sudo update-grub`

Comment: grub should automatically detect and add a windows entry. do you have them installed in the same mode?? (Legacy vs EFI)

Comment: Sorry, maybe wasn't clear - the Windows entry in the boot menu persists. What does not persist is the ability to reboot once from Ubuntu to Windows 'by default' - in other words, change the default selection one time to Windows.  Say, for instance, I am accessing computer via remote access (VNC or RDP), and need to reboot into Windows - with no one physically present, this can only be done by rebooting to a changed default entry.  The ability to do this at all is lost with Ubuntu security update.