# command to reboot into memtest86+

Tags: grub2, reboot, memory-test

is it possible to reboot directly into the memtest86+ (without giving any input during boot) , like the Windows command `mdsched` does?

Comment: You should be able to tweak the answers in https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu to apply for memtest instead of Windows.

Comment: if i use that script, it will keep booting into memtest86+ as default, while i'd like to run the tests only once.

Comment: memtest86+ runs infinitely - you must be present at restart anyway.

Comment: If you use EFI boot mode you can't run `memtest+`, there shouldn't be bootmenu entries in that case. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apropos` we can see what app is used for the next boot only:

```
$ apropos "next boot only"
grub-reboot (8) - set the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only
```

---

With using `grub-reboot` for a one-time boot, I have found that it is best to use the name of the entry and not the number of the entry like some of the [linked answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu) have had.  I just cannot get it to work with the numbers of the entries.  Here is something that I have found works with using the names of the entries.

If you cat the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` there are a lot of entries that we are looking for.  The one in particular is the `Memory test` entry.

```
$ grep -i "memory test" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
```

Since all we need is just the first entry and we need the full name of `Memory test (memtest86+)` to tell the `grub-reboot` that is what we need, we can use the following line to grab only that name and the first entry, specified by the `exit` command.

```
awk -F"'" '/Memory test/ {print $2; exit}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Which gives us output like:

```
$ awk -F"'" '/Memory test/ {print $2; exit}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Memory test (memtest86+)
```

Now we can combine that line into our one line command to reboot our system to Memtest as a one-time boot.

```
sudo grub-reboot "$(awk -F"'" '/Memory test/ {print $2; exit}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg)"; reboot
```

The `reboot` part at the end will go ahead and reboot your system for now.

Hope this helps!