# How to fix boot menu - dual boot doesn't let me select windows 10 anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have recently set up a dual boot on my computer to dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu. After some time, seemingly overnight, I was not able to boot into windows anymore. Whenever I try entering the boot menu upon launching, the computer turns itself off for a split second and boots directly into Ubuntu. After running sudo os-prober it still detects that windows is there, and looking at my disk shows that the partition that contains windows still exists. Below is a similar problem to mine which seemed to be fixed by altering GRUB and writing a script which boots the computer directly into windows: [How to reboot into Windows from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-Ubuntu)

I tried following this solution, but when executing the script it just turns off for a split second and boots right back into Ubuntu, like I tried launching the boot menu from before. I'm really not sure what to do now.

Comment: I guess your bootloader is `GRUB`. If so, try `sudo update-grub`, reboot. If the issue remain edit your question and copy-paste the output of the previous command.

Comment: You also may want to re-install grub: `sudo apt purge grub grub-pc grub-common && sudo apt install grub-pc`

Comment: If UEFI installs, can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? If not then a Windows issue. Grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows update turned fast start up back on & set hibernation flag or Windows needs chkdsk, then grub will not not it. You may then need Windows repairs if you can boot it directly from UEFI, or your Windows repair flash drive to fix it.